# GitHub page going straight to 404 page

Tags: github, github-pages, custom-error-pages

why on my GitHub page it goes straight to 404 page website doesn't[image] work

i want my website to work pls help

Comment: did you read the error message? what did you do about it? you also didn't give enough information for *anyone* to help you.

Comment: i did do everything on the error page it didnt work

Comment: how are we supposed to help with no more information then?